# Android: GridView Adapter needs to download and display images with async tasks - too slow

Tags: android, performance, gridview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I'm building an app that should make it possible to browse the images of an internet site with lots of galleries and photos. Here are the steps that the app is going through:

1. Extract URLs to albums and their images from rss feed
2. Build a ListView with every Album and one thumbnail
3. **The ListView's adapter getView() method sets every item's ImageView to a placeholder, which will be replaced with the real thumbnail by the corresponding AsyncTask**
4. The Adapter's getView() then executes an AsyncTask which fetches the image
5. The AsyncTask checks the cache first and if the picture is not there, it downloads
6. **Using WeakReferences, the AsyncTasks update (or not) the desired View with the aquired image, thus replacing the placeholder**.
7. When an Album is opened, I go through the same procedure as in step 2 but use a GridView instead of the ListView to display the album contents.

   ```
   /* GridViewAdapter.getView(...) follows */
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    ImageView thumbnail;

    // Recycle or not...
    if (convertView == null) {
      // Create new View
      thumbnail = new ImageView(mContext);
    } else {
      // Recycle View
      thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // Set the placeholder Drawable
    thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);

   if (position < amountOfPhotos) {

       if (album.getLinks().size() >= 1) {

         // imageFetcher creates an AsyncTask for every call of loadThumbnail(...)
         imageFetcher.loadThumbnail(thumbnail, album.getURL(position)); 
       }

   // Formating the ImageView a little...
   ... 

   }
   return thumbnail;
   ```

The problem is the performance of the AsyncTasks. The ListView displays on my phone around 7 items resulting in roughly a dozen simultaneous AsyncTasks when the user scrolls through the list. This is fine, the list still builds quickly.

Now the album's GridView displays 15 items at once and scrolling through the List creates many many AsyncTasks. Since some AsyncTasks have to download from the web, they stay alive for a couple of seconds. This completely slows out the AsyncTasks, which would only have to reload Bitmaps from cache.

The result is, that as long as many AsyncTasks are running, the GridView does not display images when scrolling back up, even if it just displayed them a few seconds ago. Simply because there are too many AsyncTasks.

Any suggestions on how to solve my problem? I was thinking of something like an AsyncTask factory, where I can queue jobs and set priorities. That way I could control which job is executed next and I could also control the maximum amount of AsyncTasks running at once.

It would already help me if someone could tell me if my approach sounds right in general, or if I'm completely on the wrong track with AsyncTasks here...

Comment: use [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) for download images u can see these [link1](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) , [link2](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) that's make all of your placeholder/async image downloading very, very easy !

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely look into it. Since this is my first app I was trying to avoid the extensive use of libraries. But it wouldn't hurt to check out the source code of Picasso. :)

Comment: hey @potAito I was going to give the same answer he did. Image downloading/caching is a seriously deep and complex task in Android, it's  SUPER easy to do with Picasso library.  All you do is: `Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);` and it just works

Comment: @Budius You mean it's not a shame to program it myself in this case? :) Okay I'll give it a try. I'm adding the Picasso Library now.

Comment: I'm just saying  that if someone already did such a great job like in Picasso, there's no reason to re-invent the wheel. It's super cool to understand what's going on under-the-hood, but that's about it. I can assure you that there's a lot of big apps with millions of users that heavily relies on those libraries.

Comment: @Budius You are absolutely right. I just replaced the corresponding lines in my app and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Android `3.0` AsyncTasks are executed sequentially. So it's totally possible that some long-running `AsyncTasks` will block others. In order to execute the concurrently you can use `asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);`

But generally a good solution will be to create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and execute your `Runnables` on it. This way you can control the number of tasks running and decide which order to use.

Comment: That explains a lot. So it would probably be best to only have one Task doing all the downloading and execute new tasks to simply load from cache what's already here.

Comment: The task fetching images from cache will be blocked if you do this way - because image downloading task will be executed in that time. I guess you can post the task for `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` as it will be executing tasks at least in two threads.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought that a few threads might still run in parallel once executed. Alright I'll check out what `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` can do.